# How to call async functions before the component renders in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This is the private route component, and before users access the page I need to check if they are logged in (if their token is valid)

```
import { authService } from '../authservice/AuthService';

export default function PrivateRoute({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  //const isLoggedIn = authService.isLoggedIn();
  let location = useLocation();

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />;
  }
  return children;
}
```

This is the function I'm trying to call inside the `PrivateRoute` component

```
class AuthService {

    api_domain = "http://localhost:5000"

    async isLoggedIn() {

        if (!this.getToken() || typeof this.getToken() != 'string') {
            return false
        }

        axios.get(this.api_domain + "/", {headers: {Authorization: this.getToken()}})
        .then(res => {
            if (res.data.status === 'ok') {
                return true
            }
            return false
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `isLoggedIn` function needs to be `async` is because it makes a request to your server, something which actually takes time. Therefore, what you want to be doing is displaying some sort of loading state until the user has been verified by the server.

You can create a custom hook which returns two states, `isLoading` and `isLoggedIn`, initializing `isLoading` as true:

```
export function useIsLoggedIn() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
        const token = getToken();
        if (!token || typeof token !== 'string') {
          setIsLoading(false);  
          return;
        }

        axios.get(api_domain + "/", {headers: {Authorization: token}})
        .then(res => {
            if (res.data.status === 'ok') {
                setIsLoggedIn(true);
            }
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return { isLoggedIn, isLoading };
}
```

Then, in your `PrivateRoute` component, you can use this to ensure that the verification has already happened:

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  const { isLoggedIn, isLoading } = useIsLoggedIn();
  const location = useLocation();

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; // or some other loading state
  }

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />;
  }

  return children;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect and useState hooks will help you out here.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'React';
import { authService } from '../authservice/AuthService';

export default function PrivateRoute({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  let location = useLocation();
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const isLoggedIn = async () => {
      const value = await authService.isLoggedIn();
      setLoggedIn(value);
    }

    
    // Invoke the async function
    isLoggedIn();

  }, [])
  

  if (loading){ 
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  } 

  if (!loggedIn) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />;
  }
  return children;
}
```

Comment: Since `loggedIn` is initialized as `false`, the user will be automatically navigated away to the login page before `isLoggedIn` can finish running, so this code will not have the desired effect...

Comment: That depends on where it sits in the hierarchy and the auth mechanism used. Happy to update this one also.

Comment: This would probably work with normal react but I'm using typescript

Comment: Wait .. what? @EvyatarShafran's answer is definitely more comprehensive and deserves the solution but what does either have to do with typescript?